# Angular 2: How to execute javascript code that manipulates the DOM from a template?

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to execute javascript code that accesses the DOM from within a template ?

For example, I have a canvas and I want to draw an image on it (after load), I want to do what is done on the following page, but from Angular 2 land:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-size/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ElementRef` to access DOM within template. Rest of canvas logic is similar. I created [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o9pAx3dTocoFukvw0HIJ?p=preview) for you.

Comment: Legend! Angular 2 docs and examples are lacking somewhat at the moment so this was a time saver!